# Filling Logs with Zero Data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm passing arguments into my `render()` function the following way:

```
render() {
    const { minerid, ownerid, logs, address } = this.props.miner
}
```

They are structured like so:

[image: logs]

Sometimes, the script that is sending these logs crashes. 
I have tried making this handler in order to add logs full of zeroes to the log array.

```
 handleCrash = (logs) => {
    let time = parseFloat(logs[logs.length - 1].time)
    const newTime = Date.now()

    const num = logs[logs.length - 1].gpus.num
    if ((newTime - time) > 300) {
        time = time+300

        logs.push(
            {
                gpus: {
                    fans: Array(num).fill('0'),
                    hashrate: Array(num).fill('0'),
                    temps: Array(num).fill('0'),
                    num: num
                },
                miner: logs[logs.length - 1].miner,
                time: time
            }
        )

    }
}
```

I have then tried putting this in my `componentDidMount()` :

```
componentDidMount () {
    this.handleCrash(this.props.miner.logs)
}
```

as well as putting `handleCrash()` in my render method like this:

```
render() {
    this.handleCrash(this.props.miner.logs)
    const { minerid, ownerid, logs, address } = this.props.miner
```

I have different functions manipulating this data calculating averages and graphing charts further down into the app.

They all work fine until I try to add these zero logs and I get "`Error: <path> attribute d: Expected number, "MNaN,85.926498958…`" and the graphs don't render anymore.

The zero logs look like they are the exact same structure as all the other logs.

Anyobody knows what am I doing wrong here? Thank you in advance!

Comment: It seems you are having a problem in the place you are inserting the data. Check which typeof data the input of where you render the graphs is expecting and what are you feeding in.

Comment: You can't modify react props, so the handling that you're doing in `handleCrash` won't change much since you're still getting the data from props in the render function.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
handleCrash = (logs) => {
    let time = parseFloat(logs[logs.length - 1].time)
    const newTime = Date.now()

    const num = logs[logs.length - 1].gpus.num
    if ((newTime - time) > 300) {
        time = time+300

        logs.push(
            {
                gpus: {
                    fans: Array(num).fill('0'),
                    hashrate: Array(num).fill('0'),
                    temps: Array(num).fill('0'),
                    num: num
                },
                miner: logs[logs.length - 1].miner,
                time: time
            }
        )

    }

    return logs
}

render() {
    const { minerid, ownerid, logs, address } = this.handleCrash(this.props.miner.logs)
```